# How to Read this Realtime Database firebase to flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've used the Real-Time Database with this setup:

[image]

```
late final stream = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('data').child('environment').onValue;


StreamBuilder(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final data = snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?;
      if (data == null) {
        return Text('No data');
      }
      final humidity = data['humidity'];
      final temperature = data['temperature'];
```

But how can I retrieve these values from the database?
Read That sensor and timestamp epoc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

from what I'm seeing here your getting a huge map with the firebase Id as entries

so maybe try something like:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final data = snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?;
              if (data == null) {
                return Text('No data');
              }
              data.forEach((key, value) {
                         final humidity = value['humidity'];
                         final temperature = value['temperature'];
                         print(humidity);
                         print(temperature);
                         });
```